# How to segmentize lines into dots in CARTO

Tags: postgis, carto, sql

I have this code generating a curve in Carto.

[image: map]

I want to convert it into a curve of points and then animate the points with torque.

```
WITH lines as (
      SELECT 
         a.cartodb_id,
         a.origen_oaci || '-' || b.destino_oaci as route,
         ST_Segmentize(
                ST_Makeline(
                  cdb_latlng(1,1), 
                  cdb_latlng(50,50)
                )::geography, 
                100
            )::geometry as the_geom
      FROM
        modernizacion.datos_2016_resumidos a,
        modernizacion.datos_2016_resumidos b
      WHERE
        a.cartodb_id = b.cartodb_id)
   SELECT 
     *, 
    case    when ST_XMax(the_geom) - ST_XMin(the_geom) <= 180
                then ST_Transform(the_geom,3857)
            when ST_XMax(the_geom) - ST_XMin(the_geom) > 180
                then ST_Transform(ST_Difference(ST_Shift_Longitude(the_geom),
                  ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(180 90, 180 -90)',4326),
                            0.00001)),3857)
    end as the_geom_webmercator
   FROM
    lines
```

I know I can use something like this, but I'm not being able to integrate with the code above.

```
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(
ST_Segmentize(the_geom, 1))).geom as new_the_geom FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it in this way:

```
 WITH projectedLines as (

      WITH lines as (
          SELECT 
             a.cartodb_id,
             a.origen_oaci || '-' || a.destino_oaci as route,
             ST_Segmentize(
                    ST_Makeline(
                           cdb_latlng(a.origen_lat,a.origen_lon), 
                            cdb_latlng(a.destino_lat,a.destino_lon)
                    )::geography, 
                    100000
                )::geometry as the_geom
          FROM
            modernizacion.datos_2016_resumidos a            
    )


    SELECT cartodb_id, (ST_DumpPoints(
    ST_Segmentize(the_geom, 400000000000))).geom as the_geom 

    FROM

        lines
    )



    SELECT 
        *,
        case    
        when ST_XMax(the_geom) - ST_XMin(the_geom) <= 180
            then ST_Transform(the_geom,3857)
        when ST_XMax(the_geom) - ST_XMin(the_geom) > 180
            then ST_Transform(ST_Difference(ST_Shift_Longitude(the_geom), ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(180 90, 180 -90)',4326),0.00001)),3857)
        end as the_geom_webmercator
       FROM
        projectedLines
```

this fragmented the curves into points.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into [this example](https://gist.github.com/jsanz/8aeb48a274e3b787ca57) exactly on the path you want to go. It basically generates the lines, then creates the points over them so you can animate them.

[image]

[This visualization](https://team.carto.com/u/jsanz/viz/89f6adfe-48f8-11e5-b416-0e0c41326911/public_map) is a working example of that query.

Mind also that this query does not take into account the dateline, if you need to take that, take a look to [this blog post](https://carto.com/blog/jets-and-datelines/) but it's focused in the line rendering.